# How to enable marker on hover only for a range of points in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make a line chart (x-axis shows time) in which only a range of points/markers are enabled on hover. Like from time `t1` to time `t2`, marker should be available and in other case it should be disabled.

I tried using

```
hover {
        enabled : function(){
                    if(this.x >= t1 && this.x <= t2) return true;
                    else return false;
                    }
      }
```

But `hover` didn't seem to understand anonymous function I suppose and the hover is enabled for all.
How can I achieve this thing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "points/marker are enabled on hover"? Looking at your example you seem to mean either the halo or the marker?

Comment: Yeah  sorry I meant marker on point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`series.marker.states.hover.enabled`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.states.hover.enabled):

> enabled: `Boolean`
>
> Enable or disable the point marker. Defaults to `true`.

It should be set to true/false, not an anonymous function.

If you want only some of the points to have hover state, then enable only for those points that states:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    marker: {
      states: { 
        hover: { enabled: false } // disable by default
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And points' settings:

```
series: [{
  data: [{ 
    x: ...,
    y: ...,
    marker: {
      states: {
        hover: { enabled: true }
      }
    }
  }, { 
    x: ..., // This point has disabled hover state,
    y: ..., // inherited defaults from series.
  }, { 
    x: ...,
    y: ...,
    marker: {
      states: {
        hover: { enabled: true }
      }
    }
  }]
}]
```

Comment: hey @pawel fus ,thanks for your answer , but is there any other way of doing this? i am supplying data via array which is supplied directly by making ajax call . and i don't want to manipulate it. Can u suggest any other way ? thanks

Comment: You can loop over all points before rendering a chart, something like this: `series: [{ data: data.map(hoverEnabler) }]` and `function hoverEnabler(point) { if (point.x > t1 && point.x < t2) { point.marker = { states: { hover: { enabled: true } } }; } return point; }`